# not, and, or in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators

```
not 1==2 or 3==3 and 5==6
```

How is this evaluated? I know the order is **not**, **and**, **or** (strongest to weakest)

so if i do the not first, are these the steps:

1. `not 1==2 or 3==3` which equates to `False`
2. then `False` and `False` equates to `False`

But I'm confused because the order is **not**, **and**, **or**

So why do I do the **or** first before the **and**?

Comment: That expression evaluates to True when I run it.  How did you get False as a result?

Comment: The expression contains another operator, the "==", and it has the highest priority. Does it make the evaluation clearer?

Comment: @JohnGordon yup i just ran it, sorry i made a mistake it does evaluate to True. But i posted this question cuz i was confused about why **or** is evaluated bfr **and**.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

First of all that expression gives out **True** as an output.
The operation goes on like this step by step:

```
1. (not 1==2) or (3==3 and 5==6) 
2. (True) or (True and False)
3. True or False 
4. True
```

for further reference check this out: [Operator precedence in python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: Adding to the answer, since `(not 1==2)` is `True`. `(3==3 and 5==6)` wouldn't even be evaluated due to short-circuit evaluation. For example, `True or print("This will never execute")` gives `True` but doesn't print `This will never execute`. [Try it Online!](https://godbolt.org/z/zYrE5Maf5)

Answer (score 3):

We know `not` before `and` before `or`.
`or` has logical short-circuitry - it stops as soon as one of the `or` expressions evaluates to `True` by returning `True`.
`and` has logical short-circuitry concerning the first `False` occurring for any of the elements connected by `and`.

In `(not 1==2) or (3==3 and 5==6)`:

`(not 1==2)` is already `True`. Due to logical short-circuitry we don't need to consider the rest, but know that this entire `or` expression returns then `True`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use brackets to explain how this is being treated:

`(not 1==2) or (3==3 and 5==6)`

It performs the first check of `not 1==2` which is `True`.

Let's say it equalled false, because there is an `or` next to it, it would then perform the next check of `3==3 and 5==6` which would then return `False`

Answer (score 0):

A or B returns A if A is True else it returns B
i.e lazy evaluation.

(not 1==2)---> True

This might sound dumb but the code just stops there.
the and part is not even reached

You don't believe?

`print(not 1==2 or (print('The Code Reaches Here!'),4==2)[0] and (print('The Code Reaches Here!'),4==5)[0])`

Try running this code. it will not print because the code is not reached there.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning isn't correct. You need to look at [operator-precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

so of the four operators you have, `not x`, `==`, `or`, `and`, the ordering is:

1. `==`
2. `not x`
3. `and`
4. `or`

This means `not 1==2 or 3==3 and 5==6` equates to:

1. `not (1==2) or (3==3) and (5==6) => not False or True and False`
2. `(not False) or True and False => True or True and False`
3. `True or (True and False) => True or False`
4. `True or False => True`